# Show $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}(\frac{\Gamma(k-c\lambda)}{\Gamma(k+a\lambda)})^{2}}{n^{1-2(a+c)\lambda}}=\frac{1}{1-2(a+c)\lambda}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, gamma-function

I'm trying to compute:$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}(\frac{\Gamma(k-c\lambda)}{\Gamma(k+a\lambda)})^{2}}{n^{1-2(a+c)\lambda}}=\frac{1}{1-2(a+c)\lambda}$$
where $-1<a<\frac{1-c}{2}$, $\lambda=\frac{1}{1+c}$.

I tried using $$ \lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\Gamma(n+\alpha)}{\Gamma(n) n^{\alpha}}=1, \alpha\in \mathbb{R}$$ but it didn't work out.

I'm quite sure of my result but I could not check it.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Try using $$
\left( {\frac{{\Gamma (k - c\lambda )}}{{\Gamma (k + a\lambda )}}} \right)^2  = \frac{1}{{k^{2(a + c)\lambda } }} + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{k^{2(a + c)\lambda  + 1} }}} \right)
$$ and Riemann sums.

Comment: Or apply the [Stolz–Cesàro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem_for_the_%E2%88%9E/%E2%88%9E_case) (directly).